# Playlists in Android foobar2000

Tags: android, foobar2000

In foobar2000 for Android, is there an easy way to:

1. Add all tracks under a genre into a playlist?
2. Add the currently playing track into a playlist? (when I tap the context menu (ellipsis) I only get an option to add it into the most-recently created playlist or create a new playlist)

As an extra question (if I'm allowed to ask it), if I can't do the above easily, which music player would you recommend to better suit my needs?